# GROK Filter Help Logstash

Tags: logstash, filebeat, grok

Hello I am new to GROK learning, I am trying to store following log in seperate fields, having a hard time writing a GROK filter to do it

This is the log

01/04/2021 15:30:00.300 +03:00 - [INFO] - [w3wp/LPAPI-Last Casino/95] - Log Message XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

and I want to extract in this pattern

DATE TIME TIMEZONE - [SEVERITY] - [APPLICATION/SUBSYSTEM/THREAD_ID] - MESSAGE

Comment: So far this is what I have which works till SEVERITY Level

%{DATESTAMP:TimeStamp} %{ISO8601_TIMEZONE:TimeZone} - \[%{LOGLEVEL:Severity} - \[%{DATA:APPLICATION}\/%{DATA:SUBSYSTEM}\/%{BASE10NUM:THREAD_ID}\]'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick

```
filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{DATESTAMP:TimeStamp} %{ISO8601_TIMEZONE:TimeZone} - \[%{LOGLEVEL:Severity}] - \[%{DATA:APPLICATION}/%{DATA:SUBSYSTEM}/%{BASE10NUM:THREAD_ID}] - %{GREEDYDATA}"}
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).